# Google cloud storage - Tez output files

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-cloud-storage

When I run a query using tez , the number of output files are very huge. I have some 4-5 GB of data each having 46 MB or 16 MB. I want to have only 2-3 files as output files.

My output files location will be google cloud storage. How do I merge the files?

```
set mapred.reduce.tasks = 1;
set hive.merge.mapfiles = true; 
set hive.mergejob.maponly = true;
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
```

I did set these parameters. And I did write insert overwrite query to overwrite the data in same location. No use. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this done. Earlier, when I was doing this, it was map only job. Now, I have changed the query a bit to use reducer also(Added distribute by). Then if I say "number of reducer = 1" it works. But it is not working for other parameters which should work for map only job